# Como hago para guardar imagenes en mi base de datos

Tags: java, typescript, spring-boot, imagen

Tengo mi proyecto que es full stack en angular y springboot.Pero estuve probando de guardar imagenes de los usuarios en la base de datos pero lo que se me guarda es la ruta de almacenamiento , como tengo que hacer para guardar correctamente las imagenes en la base de datos

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te está haciendo el framework es el comportamiento esperado. Lo más habitual es guardar las imágenes en una carpeta de tu servidor al subirlas y guardar en base de datos la ruta, normalmente relativa, del archivo que has subido.

Por ejemplo imagina que subes una imagen llamada `user001.jpg` y la guardas con la biblioteca que elijas en la carpeta `"/web/media/images/user/user001"`.jpg dentro de tu proyecto.

Esa es la ruta que guardarás en el sitio que elijas de tu base de datos, por ejemplo en la tabla `usuario` en un campo de tipo `varchar` llamado `profile_image`.

Ésta es la manera más fácil y más habitual de persistir imágenes en tu servidor.

Si utilizas Angular es importante que éstas imágenes las guardes en una carpeta accesible a través de una petición `http/https` para poder ver las imágenes.

Otra forma de persistir imágenes sería guardarlas directamente en la base de datos como un `blob` y convertirlas al formato elegido de nuevo al recuperarlas pero es un enfoque más difícil y menos habitual que guardar el archivo y la ruta, ya que como he mencionado con la ruta sólo tienes que acceder a la dirección del directorio.

Y para guardar imágenes de los usuarios (entiendo que de perfil) guardar la ruta es el enfoque más práctico dicho sea de paso.